# Angular 2: Using pipes with ngModel

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe, angular2-ngmodel

I was using JQuery inputmask in one of my forms along with `[(ngModel)]`, but for some reason they won't work together. Using either one by itself works perfectly fine, but combining the two completely breaks `[(ngModel)]` and new inputs don't get sent back to the component. After struggling with this for a while I figured using Angular 2's pipes would be a good solution, however I can't figure out how to get those two to work together either.

Here is some code I am using for testing my pipe

```
<input [(ngModel)]="Amount" id="Amount" name="Amount" class="form-control" type="number" autocomplete="off">
<p>Amount: {{Amount | number:'1.2-2'}}</p>
```

If I type in 12345, the `<p>` tag below will show 12,345.00, which is exactly how I want it to filter, but I don't want to have the filtered amount below the input, I want the input itself to display 12,345.00. Adding that same pipe to the `ngModel` like this: `[(ngModel)]="Amount | number:'1.2-2'"` gives me the following error.

> Parser Error: Cannot have a pipe in an action expression at column 10
>   in [Amount | number:'1.2-2'=$event]

How can I use pipes (or input masks) inside an input with `[(ngModel)]`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[(ngModel)] is a short hand for [ngModel] and (ngModelChange). If you separate them it should work (it works for sure with the async pipe):

```
[ngModel]="Amount | number: '1.2-2'" (ngModelChange)="updateAmount($event)"
```

Comment: I see, that worked great, although now I'm having an issue with the cursor position, but I should probably post a new question for that.

Comment: But where is the error itself? What's the stack? Does it get to your update handler?

Comment: The error is throwing in the decimal pipe when the value is empty: Invalid argument '' for pipe 'DecimalPipe' and it's happening on the handler when the input value is empty. I think it's Angular bug for not protecting empty values.

Comment: so you can add to your Amount a `.startWith('')`