# Angular2 using currency in ngModel

Tags: html, angular

Hello I am trying to show a currency in an input box using Angular2. Right now I have

```
<p class="list-group-item-text">${{ item.price | number : '1.2-2'}}</p>
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.price">
```

and the out put is

[image]

and what I am looking for is the text inside the box to be the same as the text above the box.

Comment: This is more of a css issue rather than angular. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913236/html-text-input-field-with-currency-symbol

Comment: Check this issue  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346676/angular-2-using-pipes-with-ngmodel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-currency-mask

Once you add this, it is as easy as adding **currencyMask** to your inputs.

```
<input currencyMask [(ngModel)]="value" />
```