# How to have different value between model and input box (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I have an application in Angular 5, and I need to have an input formatted with thousand separators (space), but my model is a number and don't allow spaces (number expected).

My application is already developped and I don't want to change all typescript, I only want to create a directive or pipe.

Example like i want :

[image]

Is it possible to have a different model of Input box ?

**Version :**

- Angular5

Steven

Comment: Show some code to us

Comment: you want the numbers seperated in the input field?

Comment: Yes in my input field I want separator, but in my model I want a value without separator.

Comment: Here is the good article about such a kind of thins (different view and model values). https://netbasal.com/angular-formatters-and-parsers-8388e2599a0e

Comment: Can you provide some plunker to play with?

Comment: Here is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39643180/1009922) to a similar question.

Comment: And [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40346864/1009922).

Comment: @ConnorsFan [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ldd4wl) This solution is not good, because the model is not a number it's string !!!
Thx Alexander, I read this post and I comeback with my result.

Comment: @StevenDieu - Are you talking about [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40346864/1009922)? The model is a number.

Comment: @ConnorsFan [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ldd4wl) I'm sorry but, look at my stackblitz it does not work.

Comment: @StevenDieu - Does [this one](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-huc5wt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) work?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Yes nice !! But ... (sorry) my application it's already developped and I have more input and I don't want to write the code in my component.ts. I prefer a generic code like directive or simple pipe without method convert... It's possible ?

Comment: I haven't done it but, according to [this article](https://blog.ngconsultant.io/custom-input-formatting-with-simple-directives-for-angular-2-ec792082976), you can create a pipe with the `transform` and the `parse` methods, so that formatting can be customized in both directions.

Comment: @ConnorsFan Ok I test this, Thx.

Comment: are you using a `pipe` to format ?

Answer (score 1):

you can create an loval variable and bind to your input. then in change event of input box cast variable to your model.

if this is helpfull tell me.